# SQL Server 2014 Column Level Security -- Suppress error on select * query

Tags: sql-server

I have an interesting problem I have found no answers to anywhere online.

A current client wants to implement column level in their SQL Server 2014 database.

This is not a hard task to implement. My question arises when the user will inevitably do a `SELECT *`, which will throw an error stating that the columns they do not have permission to view.

Is there a way to suppress the error message, and only return the columns the user has permissions to query?

Example: let's say I have three columns in a table: Column1, Column2, Column3,  and I only have permissions to view Column1 and Column3. Is there any way to return a result set containing Column1 and Column3, and not show me an error message for trying to access Column2?

I know an alternative would be to create a view, but would like to like to see if this is possible without doing so.

Comment: What you are asking for is a contradiction. Select * means "select all columns" yet you are asking for it to be "select only columns to which I have access". It doesn't work both ways.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do this or not.  My first impression though is, why are you doing `select *` instead of specifying columns?

Comment: My goal is to maximize usability.  

My current client is not staffed with technical people, and any error they receive causes confusion and things to slow down.  The conversation then becomes... "Well I don't want to type it all out, I didn't have to do that before... this is broken I can't run my business with this."

 "select all columns" yet you are asking for it to be "select only columns to which I have access" -- Yes, that's exactly what I want